# store data in memory and deliver as a json

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

My objective is to collect data from a webservice and deliver it to a client as a json. The problem is sometimes the query is just to big to store into an array and because of that im facing problems with **memory exaustion**.

To complete the query i need to send **multiple requests** to the webservice and as the data arrives i append it into an array.

When all the process finishes i return the array as a json to the user.

Im studying other ways of doing this:

1. Judy array - my structure is really big and i managed to save 50% of the memory usage with this data structure. The problem now is returning a json object from this structure in a efficient way.
2. Setting a variable and append encoded json to it. (*guessing that json is much more lightweight than a conventional array*).

Any more suggestions?

Comment: How big of data are we talking?

Comment: MongoDB? Or maybe [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/)?

Comment: @Devon one year of data can take up to 2gb or 3gb of memory. It's linear.

Comment: If you don't want to add more memory to handle the excess, write out the JSON as you go, don't store everything in an array and then convert it to JSON.  Output buffering may be another limitation here.  Depending on your web server implementation, the output may be buffered in memory until the PHP script finishes.